IntelliJ IDEA program not launching and giving me error
So I tried installing IntelliJ IDEA on my Windows 7 and when I tried to launch it, it gives me this error saying: "The procedure entry point CreateAppContainerProfile could not be located in the dynamic link library USERENV.dll.".
I was expecting it to run properly like I did installing other programs on my computer, but I got that random error. I tried to figure out and even tried googling how to fix the problem, but I couldn't figure it out.

Windows 7 is very old. I remember that upgrading to Windows 10 was free. I'm guessing that your IntelliJ IDEA installation is not compatible with Windows 7. In fact the requirements page states the following:

Microsoft Windows 10 1809 or later
Windows Server 2019 or later

I suggest that you first upgrade your Windows version.

Windows 7 doesn't fit the system requirements since 2020.1. If upgrading your OS is not possible, you need to download 2019.3 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html
